# How to correctly send header with Curl, PHP API

Tags: php, json

I am trying to use api with oauth, so that I return a token, I do not know if I am doing well with php, since in the documentation it is set in the header "-H" and -"-d" and I do not know how to apply it, the shipping method is by post

the documentation tells me the following

```
curl -X POST https://api.usa.cloud.com/oauth/token 
-H 'accept: application/json' 
-H 'Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6N3loVHI1RHNkLWg2YTktODVnZS1nNjc4OTNoNmUwdGQ' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
-d 'grant_type=client_credentials&scope=api-access'
```

I in php, I apply it like this

```
$ch = curl_init('https://myurlapi.com/oauth/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(

 'accept: application/json', 
 'Authorization: Basic ', 
 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
 'grant_type=client_credentials&scope=api-access',
 'X-Amz-Date:'.$fecha_str,


  ));


  $result = curl_exec($ch);

   curl_close($ch);

$data=json_decode($result, true);

 print_r($data);
```

and the following returns to me

```
Array ( [message] => Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization=Basic NWYxQ3YmY2ZZjNl9yd19pZDpAV)
```

I have the feeling that somewhere something is missing or I am not using curl correctly in php,

edit with the solution, as they have put in a colleague is as simple as using the online tool curl to php that is in google

Comment: `'Authorization: Basic ',` - where's the rest of this?

Comment: I deleted it because it contained the full key

Comment: Okay, but it is still contained in the original cURL request you have shown first.

Comment: `grant_type=client_credentials&scope=api-access` - that is not a _header_ in your original cURL commend.

Comment: (FYI: Several online tools to convert cURL to PHP cURL code can be found when you type "curl to php" into Google.)